# How to concat npm_package_config variable inside the single quotes

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-config

In package.json I have following configuration:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "api:update": "curl -k -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=$npm_package_config_session'  -o api-docs.json https://localhost:8445/v2/api-docs",
    ...
  }
```

Variable is defined using following command:
 `npm config set project:session XXXX`

When `npm config get project:session` is executed I get proper value.

Any suggestion how to resolve $npm_package_config_session inside the single quotes?

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding using double quotes as the shell intends?

Comment: No real reason, looks like it works with double quotes: `"api:update": "curl -k -H \"Cookie: JSESSIONID=$npm_package_config_session\"  -o api-docs.json https://localhost:8445/v2/api-docs --verbose"`. Thnx for the tip!